# Playing two audio streams simultaneously

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-streaming, windows-phone

I am going to write an application that will play two audio streams simultaneously from an HTTP streaming server. Before I begin, I want to be sure whether the Windows Phone devices and API supports this.

I guess I'll have to use two instances of MediaElement's. Any ideas or suggestions?

Edit: I tried it with the following code, and the first one stops and second one plays, when I start the second one while the first one is playing:

```
    private void StopMedia1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        media1.Stop(); 
    } 

    private void PauseMedia1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        media1.Pause(); 
    } 

    private void PlayMedia1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        media1.Play(); 
    } 

    private void StopMedia2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        media2.Stop(); 
    } 

    private void PauseMedia2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        media2.Pause(); 
    } 

    private void PlayMedia2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        media2.Play(); 
    } 



<Grid> 
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> 
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <MediaElement x:Name="media1" Source="1.mp3" Margin="0,151,0,359" /> 
    <MediaElement x:Name="media2" Source="2.mp3" Margin="0,154,3,359" Grid.Column="2" /> 
    <!-- Stops media playback.--> 
    <Button Click="StopMedia1" Content="Stop" Margin="6,449,24,244" /> 
    <!-- Pauses media playback. --> 
    <Button Click="PauseMedia1" Content="Pause" Margin="0,538,24,143" /> 
    <!-- Begins media playback. --> 
    <Button Click="PlayMedia1" Content="Play" Margin="0,649,0,47" /> 
    <Button Click="PauseMedia2" Content="Pause" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="154,524,6,169" Grid.Column="1" /> 
    <Button Click="PlayMedia2" Content="Play" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,612,12,59" /> 
    <Button Click="StopMedia2" Content="Stop" Margin="18,429,12,264" Grid.Column="2" /> 
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easy enough to try it, yeah?

Comment: Yes, and I tried, but had no success. The first one stops when I start the second one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to play two MediaElements at the same time in Windows Phone 7/7.5.
To do that you would need to use the [SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282429) class from XNA, althought I don't think that supports streaming.